# User defined type guards for array element type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typeguards

I am trying to code a user defined type guard that check the types of the element of an array.

This is what I have:

```js
const isArray = <T>(o: any | any[]): o is T[] => {
  return Array.isArray(o)
}
```

So I can call it this way

```js
const func = function(arg: string | string[] | number | number[]) {
  if (isArray<string>(arg)) {
    console.log(arg)
  } else {
    console.log(arg)
  }
}
```

This check that arg is an array of string.

I can also use it this way:

```js
const func = function(arg: string | string[] | number | number[]) {
  if (isArray(arg)) {
    console.log(arg)
  } else {
    console.log(arg)
  }
}
```

And now, it's checking is an array (`string[]` or `number[]` here). But the problem it's that the type guard can be called with random generic type, for example `Boolean` resulting in a weird behavior.

So I went for this function:

```js
const isArray = <T extends U, U>(o: U | U[]): o is T[] => {
  return typeof o === 'object' && typeof o['length'] === 'number'
}
```

So now, there is a constraint on the type guard. If I call it this way:

```js
isArray<string, typeof arg>(arg)
```

I will have an error if the first generic type is not one of the arg types. This leads to a new issue.

```js
const func = function(arg: string[] | number[]) {
  if (isArray<string, typeof arg>(arg)) {
    console.log(arg)
  } else {
    console.log(arg)
  }
}
```

In this case, I will have an error because `string` is not part of arg types.

So I have to issues:

- Is there a way to fix the second generic (`typeof arg`) ? It would be great that it is hardcoded and that user doesn't have to provide it every time he uses the type guard
- Is there a way to say, "this generic must be of the type of the element of the arrays passed as argument". As example `string | number` if `isArray` is called with a parameter of type `number[] | string[]`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you want to achieve. Do you want to make sure that your array is homogeneous?

Comment: Yes, and I try to create a smart enough function so it can be called for every type passing a generic type. And also, add constraints to that type so that the final user of the type guard can't call it passing non-coherent parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do makes little sense to me.
Seems like your type guards are lying - they assert blindly that if something is an Array it's an Array of a given type.

Your type guard should check if the array members are indeed of the given type, and since you can't know the given type at *runtime* (which is when the type guard is running), you can't do it in a generic way.

For example, `isStringArray` can be written like this:

```
const isStringArray = (arg: any): arg is string[] => {
   return Array.isArray(arg) && arg.every(item => typeof item === 'string')
}
```

The check must be specific to the type you want to assert.

Comment: Worth adding that using generic parameter without corresponding value - is almost always unsafe

Comment: Well thanks to the Dude. I hadn't type check every item so yes, my type guard was broken.

Captain-Yossarian, what do you mean ? Declaring a generic put not passing a value to it when the function is called:

const func = function<T>(arg: T) {} and then func(foo) ?

Comment: It's better to type `arg` as `unknown`, not `any`